# How to target md-toolbar-row element in md-toolbar

Tags: css, flexbox, angular-material2

I am trying to put `justify-content:center` to center the content of the toolbar. On targeting the toolbar I can see the expanded elements and one of them is `md-toolbar-row` to which giving `justify-content:center` centers the content(centers only while debugging through developer tools).

Here is the plunker:https://plnkr.co/edit/qh3Kqi9GDXIL4H1HTzFu?p=preview

How do I center the content?

Tried following but none helps:

```
md-toolbar-row{
justify-content:center;
}

.mat-toolbar-row{
justify-content:center;
}

.mat-toolbar .mat-toolbar-row{
justify-content:center;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As the flex direction is *column* you should use `align-items: center` to horizontally center it

```
md-toolbar {
  align-items: center;
}
```

[Updated Plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/rVnzK3qrJJKpmG7a161g?p=preview)

---

Optionally you can change the flex direction and use `justify-content: center;`

```
md-toolbar {
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

[Updated Plnkr 2](https://plnkr.co/edit/2xZts742JrDX3BylfCGB?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to center content for only this toolbar then use the `example-spacer` class. Make the following change in the class and add it before the `<div>` tag.

Plnkr [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/9nhJinu7DLGYYsumg3f3?p=preview)

css:

```
.example-spacer {
  flex: .5 1 auto;
}
```

html:

```
<md-toolbar color="primary">
  <span class="example-spacer"></span>
  <div>Custom Toolbar</div>
</md-toolbar>
```

Comment: Good for a single toolbar but adds overhead if one has multiple toolbars in their page. +1